# Developer Paypal application disappeared

Tags: paypal

I've created 6 months ago an app on http://developer.paypal.com. I have created some accounts to test in sandbox mode. Yesterday I checked the http://developer.paypal.com account and I saw that my application disappeared, but the PayPal token that I have in my PHP application is working.

Where i can check the PayPal app ?

Comment: How did you do? I am facing the same problem, I made an app with the MPL library one year ago, but now It's disappeared, I can still use payments and all work with my app id.

Answer (score 1):

developer.paypal.com is the only portal for you to check your REST app. If the issue still persist, you might need to file a ticket via https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask

Their technical support will check this for you.